# Запустить из книги excel 2003 (vba) сторонее приложение exe как модальное окно

Tags: excel

Здравствуйте Уважаемые программисты Excel!
Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить код ниже (excel 2003 vba), чтобы запущенное из книги с Листа1 сторонее приложение "v5.exe" открылось как модальное окно, т.е. "заморозило" все действия с книгой до тех пор, пока не будет завершен процесс "v5.exe" (win xp и win 7)? Другими словами, как запустить приложение "v5.exe"(это окно с полями) как обычную форму excel? Спасибо!

```
Dim MyPath
MyPath = Shell(Environ("temp") & "\" & "v5.exe " & Chr(34) & ThisWorkbook.FullName & Chr(34), 1)
```

Comment: Не выйдет. Эксель зависнет на время ожидания.

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь *Windows Script Host*
используем `WScript.Shell`:

```
Dim FullPath As String
Dim wsh As Object
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean 
Dim windowStyle As Integer

Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
waitOnReturn = True
windowStyle = 1
FullPath = Environ("temp") & "\" & "v5.exe " & Chr(34) & ThisWorkbook.FullName & Chr(34)

wsh.Run FullPath, windowStyle, waitOnReturn
MsgBox "End v5.exe"
```

Comment: Спасибо большое , буду пробовать.

Comment: @olga Пишите, если возникнут проблемы

Comment: Попробовала код выше: при запуске приложения "v5.exe" книга excel как-будто висит, но реагирует на нажатия, т.е. если щелкнуть по крестику для закрытия книги excel, то после завершения процесса "v5.exe" - книга закрывается, чего не хотелось бы.
Может быть можно каким-то способом запустить на заднем фоне с приложением "v5.exe" модальную форму excel (userform1.show 1), а после завершения процесса "v5.exe" форму выгружать?
Спасибо!

Comment: @olga. Нет, если только вы, предварительно сами каким-либо образом не заблокируете весь Excel. Посудите сами, вы из одного процесса, запускаете другой процесс и это, если еще примитивно рассматривать. Вот показать модально форму из VBA - вы можете. И, вот оттуда, можно попробовать и вызвать указанный выше код

Comment: Спасибо большое!